# highlighting only the selected item in the listview in Android

Tags: android, listview, selecteditem

I have a list view `contactslist`. I wrote the code for highlighting the selected item in the `ListView`. It is working. When I click on one item it is highlighting that item, but the problem is if I click on another item it is highlighting that one too. I want to highlight the selected item only. The previous selection should go away when I click on another item.

```
arg1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.highlighter);
```

This is the code in the click listener using to highlight the selected item. How can I fix this?

I'm setting the background of the rows in the adapter:

```
public int[] colors = new int[]{0xFFedf5ff, 0xFFFFFFFF}; 
public int colorPos; 

[...]
colorPos = position % colors.length; 
row.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
```

Comment: if the answer is acceptable i can accept dat.but if the answer doesnt help me den how can i accept that?

Comment: If you're not satisfied with the answers, just forget the boost part of my previous comment. But some more information would really help us to figure out where your problem roots, and how to help you. thank you!

Comment: i am using relative layout.i am setting the background for the list view using adapter,my logic is if the rawnum is an odd one give background color and if it s even number give another background color.below is the logic implementation.public int[] colors = new int[]{ 0xFFedf5ff, 0xFFFFFFFF};
 public int colorPos;
  colorPos = position % colors.length; 
  row.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);

Comment: please from now on rather edit your question to share code snippets, than paste them in comments, since here they are not quite readable. It would also be helpful, if you'd provide the code in which you handle the selected background. thanks!

Comment: thanks....but not yet got d solution.i m stuck on this.plz help me

Comment: I've posted an answer based on what i understood from your question, I hope I got it right, and can help solve your problem.

Comment: For future references, this works: http://www.michenux.net/android-listview-highlight-selected-item-387.html

Answer (score 125):

`ListViews` by default don't have a `choiceMode` set (it's set to `none`), so the current selection is not indicated visually.

To change this, you just need to set the `choiceMode` attribute of your `ListView` to `singleChoice`. 
If you'd like custom background for the selected items in your list, you should also set the `listSelector` attribute. There you can specify not only colors, but drawables (images, layer-/state-drawables).

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/my_list"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" 
        android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray" />
```

If you don't use a `ListView` directly, but a `ListActivity`, then these attributes need to be set from code, so you should extend your activity's `onCreate` method with these lines:

```
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
getListView().setSelector(android.R.color.darker_gray);
```

So if you were using a click listener to change the background of the selected row, remove that from your code, and use the proper method from above.

*Reply to the update*

If you set the background from your getView method, instead of using a static color, apply a state list drawable to the row background with duplicateParentState set to true. This way it will change its display based on the current state of the item: normal, focused, pressed, etc.

Comment: i tried this code,but if i make the listview choice_mode_single den the first selected item is highlighting,but if i selct another item it s not highlighting.

Comment: is there any method or proprty to get previous selected item in the listview?

Comment: did you remove the code where you set the background using an onitemclick listener?

Comment: I'm using `android.support.v4.app.ListFragment`. adding the line `getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);` in onCreate() gives me Exception: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #90: Error inflating class fragment`

Comment: I've tried many combinations in the past but encountered the issue again recently. I wonder if it's device specific, my 2.3 device had the same issue as Youngjae was having.

Comment: It works great, but getSelectedItem returns null, and if dig deeper, then getSelectedItemPosition returns -1. How to make these methods return a correct value?

Answer (score 30):

In the listview xml add the "singleChoice" mode

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    (...) >
</ListView>
```

In the list item layout add

> android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator

example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator">

     <!-- your item content-->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why is this not the first thing that comes up on Google!? I've been trying for hours to get this to work. I tried all sorts of states and combinations of states (selected, activated, focused, etc..) in a selector drawable with `android:listSelector="@drawable/theSelector"` set but when it worked it was buggy (the selection indicator would sort of stay stuck while i scrolled the list, even staying in between two items sometimes). This finally made it work properly. THANK YOU.

Comment: I love one-liners... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8):

A better way is
in your theme, 
 @drawable/list_selector

list_selector.xml :

```
<!-- <item android:drawable="@color/android:transparent"  android:state_selected="true" /> -->
<item android:drawable="@color/list_bg" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/list_bg" android:state_activated="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>
```

then set background for root of your list_row.xml  android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"

Answer (score 0):

Try this at `onListItemClick`

```
view.getFocusables(POSITION);
view.setSelected(true);
```

It highlights the selection.