# How can I always highlight curent item in the listview?

Tags: android, android-listview

Now I am using:

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/bg_list_item"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
```

where bg_list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_selected="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient android:startColor="#0000ff"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_focused="false"
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:state_selected="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient android:startColor="#ff0000"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

BUT first item  is not working and selected item is not highlighting sometimes on scroll (when I am near top/bottom of my listview) and never on listView.setSelection(index).

Does I must to highlight current item programmaticaly?

Comment: http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-customized-listview.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define a custom adapter and in its getView() method:

```
private int selectedItem;

// is used outside the adapter for example OnItemClickListener
public void setSelectedItem(int position) {
    selectedItem = position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   //...
   // set selected item
    LinearLayout activeItem = (LinearLayout) rowView;
    if (position == selectedItem)
    {
       activeItem.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_dark_blue);
    }
    else
    {
       activeItem.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border02);
    }
   //...
}
```

background_dark_blue.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" >

            <solid android:color="@color/lightBlue6" />
            <!-- border width and color -->

            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#FF0404B4" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="2dp"
                android:left="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:top="2dp" />
        </shape></item>

</layer-list>
```

border02.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <stroke android:width="0.5dp" android:color="#FF000000" />
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
            <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp"
                android:bottom="0dp" />
            <corners android:radius="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>


</layer-list>
```

Comment: breceivemail, Please change ActiveItem to activeItem)

Answer (score 3):

This is because there is not a selected item in touchmode.  See [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/12/touch-mode.html) for an explanation.

You can do it with a selector, but it requires three things...

1) You must make the list row chooseable

```
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

2) Add to your selector file a condition for the activated state:

```
    <item android:state_activated="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"> 
        <gradient android:startColor="#0000ff"/>
```

3) You need create a custom adapter to track the state of each position in your list so you can maintain the proper state when scrolling.

**EDIT**

breceivemail's answer is more suited to your needs.  Mine, while it would work, would work better for a multiple checked item type list (by changing it to CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE), and is more work for what you need than is necessary.

Comment: I used breceivemail's answer with your comment about CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE and it works fine!
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

"android:listSelector" property is used to specify item background when it is clicked. To highlight the first item or the one selected after click you will need to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

ListViews by default don't have a `chioceMode` set (it's set to `none`), so the current selection is not indicated visually. Playing around with the `choiceMode` attribute will get you to the desired aspect.

You could take a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853719/highlighting-the-selected-item-in-the-listview-in-android/5854783#5854783) as well, maybe it will work for you too.