# Changing backround color of row in listview for Android app

Tags: android

I have a list view with multi columns... Want to change the background color of a row item that is selected or clicked. Have referred to various articles on stackoverflow but they dont seem to help...What i ve done in OnItemClick is .setBackgroundColor. Cannot use the selector as  would want to remember the color change in the sense the row that I have changed color for, when the application relaunches should remember the change...I put the flag value in database and can set the color in getView but how to do it for first time?  Here is the code.....

```
public class AdminMultiColumn extends Activity
{
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list;
    ArrayList<String> al;
     AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  
    {  
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
       setContentView(R.layout.admin_checkoutlist);  

      lview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.admin_list);  
      populateList();  
      Admin_checkoutlist adapter = new Admin_checkoutlist(this,list);  
      lview.setAdapter(adapter);  
    }  


    private void populateList() {  

        list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();  

        al = new ArrayList<String>();

        testday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        testmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
        testyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        dateget = testday+"-"+testmonth+"-"+testyear;

        mdb.open();
        va.open();
        Cursor c1 = va.getNameTimeinTimeout(dateget);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(c1);
        if(c1.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{ 
                idfromdb = c1.getString(0);
                al.add(idfromdb);
                namefromdb = c1.getString(1);
                al.add(namefromdb);
                timefromdb = c1.getString(2);   
                al.add(timefromdb);
                timeoutfromdb = c1.getString(3);
                al.add(timeoutfromdb);

              }while(c1.moveToNext());
        }
        c1.close();
        va.close();
        mdb.close();
        Log.d("pavan","data retrived "+namefromdb+" "+timeoutfromdb+" "+timefromdb+" "+idfromdb);

        for(int i = 0;i<al.size();i=i+4)
        {
            temp   = new HashMap<String,String>();  
            temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, al.get(i));  
            temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, al.get(i+1));
            temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, al.get(i+2));
            temp.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, al.get(i+3));

            Log.d("pavan","test here for admin");
            list.add(temp); 
        }   
    }
    //adapter class goes here////////////
    public class Admin_checkoutlist extends BaseAdapter implements OnItemClickListener   
    {

        public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list;  
        Activity activity;   

        public Admin_checkoutlist(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list) 
        {  
            super();  
            this.activity = activity;  
            this.list = list;  
        }  

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list.size(); 
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int pos) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list.get(pos);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int pos) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
        public class ViewHolder 
        {  
            TextView txtFirst;  
            TextView txtSecond;  
            TextView txtThird;
            TextView txtFOURTH;
        }  

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {   
            LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();  

            if (convertView == null)  
            {  
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.temp, null);  
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.txtFirst = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.uid); 
                holder.txtSecond = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.nametext); 
                holder.txtThird = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkintext);
                holder.txtFOURTH = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkouttext);
                convertView.setTag(holder); 
                lview.setOnItemClickListener(this);     
            }  
            else  
            {  
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  
            }             
            HashMap<String, String> map = list.get(position);  
            holder.txtFirst.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));  
            holder.txtSecond.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));  
            holder.txtThird.setText(map.get(THIRD_COLUMN));
            holder.txtFOURTH.setText(map.get(FOURTH_COLUMN));
            return convertView;  
        }//getview ends here.

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int pos,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Object  listItem = parent.getFirstVisiblePosition()+pos+1;
            //lview.getChildAt(pos).setBackgroundColor(R.color.blue);

            view.setBackgroundColor(pos);
            idtosend = listItem.toString();

            Log.d("pavan","id is"+idtosend);

            /////alert displaing block starts here////////////////////////////////
                     alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AdminMultiColumn.this);            
                        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Alert");    
                        alertDialogBuilder
                            .setMessage("Check out now")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                    // if this button is clicked, close
                                    // current activity
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checkout successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    testhour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                                    testmin = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                                    testsec = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                                    timings = testhour+":"+testmin+":"+testsec;

                                        mdb.open();
                                        va.open();
                                        va.upDate(idtosend,timings);
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "update the checkout options "+timings, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        va.close();
                                        mdb.close();    

                                        /*Intent go = new Intent(AdminMultiColumn.this,MultiColumn.class);
                                        startActivity(go);*/
                                }
                              })
                            .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });                  
                            // create alert dialog
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();           
                            alertDialog.show();              
                 ///////alert displaing block ends here//////////////////////////////////           
        }

    }

}
```

What I have done now is within the getView method, taking the convertView and setting the background resource to a color, that too is not working...below is the code...

```
 if(holder.txtFOURTH!=null)
   {
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.image_border);
   }
   else
   {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038040/android-listview-selector-color see this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There two points -

1. `pos` is not a good option as color
2. Instead of `view.setBackgroundColor(pos);` sue

> ```
> LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.list_row);
>         if(null!=row){
>             //<listAdapter>.notifyDataSetChanged();
>             row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.);
>         }
> ```

- assuming the your list row has LinearLayout in root having id "list_row", chage this as per your layout.

but there will be problem this as when you click on the second row it also be selected stated and better to call `list.notifydatasetchaged` there are few more option look over them, may fill your requirement

1. [android-selected-state-listview-example](http://bestsiteinthemultiverse.com/2009/12/android-selected-state-listview-example/)
2. [android-how-do-i-highlight-a-row-in-listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925892/android-how-do-i-highlight-a-row-in-listview)
3. [highlighting-the-selected-item-in-the-listview-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853719/highlighting-the-selected-item-in-the-listview-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for sharing these Dheeresh. Will let u know the results

Comment: None of these is helping me :(

Comment: and the solution provided by me (with notifyDataSetChanged) ?

Comment: Dheeresh, dont have a linearlayout for the rows as you said...Actually, have not understood it completely but the others are not helping

Comment: Paste the code of temp.xml file in layout folder R.layout.temp

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12526/discussion-between-kunal-shah-and-dheeresh-singh)

Comment: Can you come forward to the chat room?

Comment: Hi Dheeresh, the issue was resolved with a simple change as I had said in the chat..

Comment: We stupid guys were trying to compare a textview obj with a string that would faillll.........me bad, and am sorry to trouble u