# Set ListView item background at onCreate

Tags: android, listview, background, listviewitem

I have a listview, and I want to set the background color of the first item at onCreate. I tried this:

```
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
    DrawerListAdapter adapter = new DrawerListAdapter(this, mNavItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    View view = mDrawerList.getChildAt(1);
    view.setBackgroundColor((parseColor("#008CC3")));
```

But it gives NPE. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already have your own `ListAdapter` (`DrawerListAdapter`) class you should be able to override the `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method in it. In there you can simply do

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    if (position == 0) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#008CC3"));
    }
    return view;
}
```

Additional tips:

- You want to get the first item but are calling `getChildAt(1)`, this will actually give you the **second** item.
- `ListViews` are somehow deprecated, you should look into `RecyclerViews`

Comment: Could you show me the exact code that I should paste in there?

Comment: Updated the comment. Assuming it's extending `ListAdapter` or `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: Thank you. But later how can I change it back to transparent? Because I tried to do that on onItemClick, but it's not working.

Comment: mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new      AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor((parseColor("#008CC3")));
                parent.getChildAt(lastPosition).setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
                selectItemFromDrawer(position);
                lastPosition = position;
            }
        });

Comment: The lastPosition is set to 0 by default, so that on the first click the first item's background turns transparent.

Comment: I guess for that check other solutions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853719/highlighting-the-selected-item-in-the-listview-in-android

Comment: I accept your answer, because it does what I wanted, even though it doesn't completely solve my problem.